# Passport authentiation middleware res not found

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware, passport-local

I have below code base

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'emailAddress',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
},
 function(req,username, password, next) {
   var res =""; // this is the real issue, I don't know where to find res, or what should I initialize to re
   console.log('psprt val');
   userController.ValidateLogin(req,res,function(userDetails){
      req.user = userDetails;
      return next(null,userDetails);
    });
 }));
```

**userController.ValidateLogin** returns error in a format like

```
userController.ValidateLogin = function(req,res,userDetails) {
    return res.send({ Status:403, Msg: "Not allowed" });
}
```

But it says res.send not a function as there is res undefined , how to send res so that I have have this kind of message in return

Comment: Show us where the offending line of code `return res.send({ Status:403, Msg: "Not allowed" });` is.  Show us the code for `usercontroller.ValidateLogin()`.  That's where the issue is.

Comment: this is from validate login functin

Comment: Yeah, so show us the code for that function!

Comment: Paste the code of the `ValidateLogin()` function.

Comment: you can see I have given res=' ' above, since I don't have res

Comment: Why do you have `var res ="";` in your code?

Comment: Yes That is the issue, because I don't know where to find res

Comment: 'res' should be HTTP outgoing message not a string.

Comment: `res` is defined as a string variable in your code so `res.send()` does not exist.

Comment: "'res' should be HTTP outgoing message not a string" -- How should I give that

Comment: `ValidateLogin()` is a controller so it should be having 'res' already, what library are you using to implement your controllers?

Comment: valiatelogin is being called from passportjs authenticate middleware, and as much I know passportjs does not carry res

Comment: Like, in express you have a controller like `controller('/path', (req, res) => {//process})`

Comment: I think you are using passport in a wrong way.

Comment: Please refer the strategy you are trying to use [here](http://www.passportjs.org/)

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa , I have implemented this way becuase I had to customize many things, I am not going to change this, becuase All of my code is running and working as expected but only this part is not working

Comment: `function(req,username, password, next)` part does not take `req`. It is username, password and a callback (`next` in your case)

Comment: (passReqToCallback: true) allow me to carry req

Comment: But that is request object and you want a response object too, consider going through [this](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to send response from configuration middleware(which can be used only for passport configuration where we validate user). You need to authenticate and validated user and return back, Following code may help you,

```
userController.ValidateLogin = function(req,res,callback) {
    return callback({ Status:403, Msg: "Not allowed" });
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00  Sending a response from a middleware defeats the purpose of using a middleware.

Comment: @jfriend00 we can send response from middleware but I am referinfg provided middleware where we can not send response, you may refer doc

Comment: They are from these kind of tasks(like validating a user).

Comment: @ArifKhan How can I send it as response from middleware

Comment: When the request comes into the middleware, you check if the user is valid or not and if not valid then return the response right then.

Comment: @jfriend00 as I mention `configuration middleware` provided by passportjs, if you think that can be possible, please share

Comment: @ArifKhan, I am able to get response { Status:403, Msg: "Not allowed" }, but how to send it as response form middleware so that it will not continue to next middleware

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam you would like to utilise callback function `next()`

Comment: I tried it return next(userDetails,null); but it is taking me to next middlware rather than stop execution furhter

Comment: I did but it is not stopping chain

Comment: @jfriend00 we are talking about passportjs middleware `passport.use()` not expressjs middleware

Comment: Sorry it is stopping but it does not return in json , it returns in object, sorry for confusion, this is my first project in node, how can i parse json

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam use `next(null, false, { message: userDetails.Msg })`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172555/discussion-between-arif-khan-and-md-parvez-alam).

Comment: req.socket.destroy is not a function

Comment: I have to just show whatever coming from validation function, I think I need to parse it into json, i trined JSON.parse(userdetails) but not working

Comment: next(JSON.stringify(userDetails));  showing message correcting but not able to pase in json

Comment: next(userDetails) in postman showing [object,object] rather than json